# How to add HTML without a DIV (GWT)

Tags: gwt, html, html-lists

I'm trying to create a menu dynamically (with some data from my database), the problem occurs when i try to add new menu item "li" with gwt HTML composite or with HTMLPanel, the li added inside a div element! and that break my style and break the menu, what can do to add html without div in gwt??

```
<ul style="display: none;" id="agence-id" class="submenu">      
<div class="gwt-HTML">
<li>
<a id="P45O421">  
<i class="icon-double-angle-right">
</i>P45O421</a>
</li>
</div>
<div class="gwt-HTML">
<li>
<a id="c2">  
<i class="icon-double-angle-right">
</i>c2
</a>
</li>
</div>
<div class="gwt-HTML">
<li>
<a id="c3">   
<i class="icon-double-angle-right"></i>c3</a>
</li>
</div>
<div class="gwt-HTML">
<li>
<a id="c4">   
<i class="icon-double-angle-right">
</i>c4</a>
</li>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create the `HTMLPanel` with the constructor where you can set the tag: `HTMLPanel("li", yourHTML);`. This will use the `li` instead of the standard `div`.

Comment: i've used another way but just to avoid the problem by adding my html("ul " and "li"s ) dynamically in String before adding it to HTMLPanel , but ur solution is the best, thank u :)

Answer (score 3):

You can create Li elements by using dete Document.get().createLIElement() method and then add them to your ul element.
When you call RootPanel.get("YOURID").you get the ul element, since you have given it an id and therefor can find it in the DOM:

Codeexample:

```
import com.google.gwt.dom.client.Document;
import com.google.gwt.dom.client.LIElement;

...

HeadingElement liElement = Document.get().createLIElement();
liElement.setInnerText("This is a Li(l1) element!");
RootPanel.get("agence-id").getElement().appendChild(liElement );
```